# Algorithm to find individual, closed groups of lines in a large set of connected lines

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph, coordinates

I'm currently trying to write an algorithm that can find individual groups of connected lines within a larger set of lines. The images below should explain this a bit more clearly.

[image: Connected lines before]

[image: Groups of lines after]

In the first image you can see a set of lines. What I'm trying to do is split those lines into 3 groups, as seen in the second image. The red and green groups share a line.

I can assume that each line has a start and an end coordinate, and each line can belong to one or more groups.

I'm currently trying to write a recursive function that follows each line until it reaches an end point with one or more lines it can follow. At this point the function recalls itself until it's followed the lines back round to the split point. However this is proving unsuccessful.

The output of this example, as shown in the second image, should be 3 separate groups of lines, stored in a list. I'm currently using c#, however I should be able to use a suitable algorithm in any language, including pseudocode. I know there must be an algorithm that can achieve this, however I cannot seem to work it out or find it online.

Comment: It is really hard to give advice without seeing some of your existing code.

Comment: As it's currently written this question fits better to [ComputerScience](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You could try to fill the whole area by repeatedly using a [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm. The new starting point for the next fill operation is a not yet filled pixel. This would identify connected sub-areas surrounded by closed polygons.

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter, I wasn't sure where the best place to post was. Can I repost this question in the ComputerScience forum without it being removed as a duplicate?

Comment: @JoeMorgan: sure

Answer (score 1):

In the language of graph theory (where vertices are all the line endpoints and each edge is a line), your problem is to find all the faces of a planar graph. This is sometimes called planar face traversal. There are some resources you could consult for information on this, including [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23811/reporting-all-faces-in-a-planar-graph). Though it is a C++ library and not C#, the [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/graph/doc/planar_face_traversal.html) has an API for planar face traversal, and consulting its documentation could be helpful.